# event.which and event.keyup not working in firefox or both

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to alert when the user presses "Enter" key, Chrome works with "event.which" but it doesn't seem to work in Firefox.
And "event.keyup" doesn't seem to work in both browsers.

html:

```
   <body ng-app="myApp">
      <div ng-controller="ctrl">

        <input type="text" ng-keyup="searchEnter()" placeholder="enter the text"/>

    </div>
  </body>
```

script:

```
 <script>
    var app=angular.module("myApp",[]);
     app.controller("ctrl", ['$scope',function($scope){

      $scope.searchEnter=function() {

      if(event.which==13){
       alert("u pressed enter key");
       }
     };

    }]);
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass event to your `keyup` function and use `event` inside function.

```js
var app=angular.module("myApp",[]);
     app.controller("ctrl", ['$scope',function($scope){

      $scope.searchEnter=function(event) {

      if(event.which==13){
       alert("u pressed enter key");
       }
     };

    }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
      <div ng-controller="ctrl">

        <input type="text" ng-keyup="searchEnter($event)" placeholder="enter the text"/>

    </div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the `event` object in the function

```
$scope.searchEnter=function(event){
//rest of code
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work, like told in the above solution, need to pass Event as parameter for the function searchEnter($event) and again use it inside the function